# How to set LatLngBounds in with google place api (Android) so that it should cover the whole city?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using google places api, in that **LatLngBounds** has to be specify, I want that should be dynamically **change according to the city and cover the whole city**. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by cover the whole city? A LatLng is a specific point

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/LatLngBounds)
Check out the link , this variable has to be specified in finding place autocomplete , or do you know any other way so that can I specify the city name instead to get result.

Comment: Could you not specify the LatLng of the city and then set the zoom on the map far enough out so that the user can see the whole city?

Comment: Not showing map... Its places api.. [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google place api then you can search any city name etc. from this api you can also find lat long of that location,save them and find you current latlong and then you can draw a path over map by using your current location as a source and your search by location as destination of the path...